# Render a new view upon json

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json

I am trying to build something really simple but I am bit confused. I have a customer controller with 2 actions, index and identification. The views of these actions simply display an image each. What I want to do is be able to change from the index view to the identification view when an ios app sends a simple json get request (it could be post, doesn"t really matter as I only want to change the view). My customer_controller.rb is

```
def index
    respond_to do |format|
        format.html # index.html.erb
        format.json {render 'identification'}
    end
  end

  def identification
    @date = Time.now.strftime("%A, %d %B %Y")
    @time = Time.now.strftime("%H:%M %p")
  end
```

My routes.rb is

```
get "customer/index"
  post "customer/index"
  get "customer/identification"
```

Can anyone point me to the right direction as to what I am doing wrong? Whenever the ios app sends a json nothing happens.

Answer (score 0):

When you call `render 'identification'` that only tells rails to use the 'identification' template, it does not actually call the `#identification` method.

Comment: How should I do it then? Excuse me but it's one of my first attempts and I can't seem to work this out.

Comment: I am not really sure what you're trying to do. It looks like you can have a post to index, but if the post format is in json, you want to render the identification template? All you're lacking is setting the `@date` and `@time`.

Comment: I am really sorry for the very late response...I am trying to combine a simple iOS app with my rails app. I want to know when a button is pushed in the iOS app and have my page changed from the index to the identification. When the button is pushed the iOS app sends me a JSON get request. And I want my page changed when the JSON is send (the button is pushed).